# Solving $ \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2 + 2y(x) + 200} = 1 $

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $ y(x) $ be a function of $ x $. How can I solve this differential equation?

$$
\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2 + 2y(x) + 200} = 1.
$$

I think I need to integrate both sides with $ \int dx $ but I don't know how that would lead me to a solution.

What substitutions for the denominator would make the integral on the left side solvable?

Comment: Simply rewrite $\int f(y) y' dx=\int f(y)dy$ no substitution needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiply by $dx$ and integrate $\int \frac{y'dx}{y^2+2y+200} =x+C$.
Substitute $t=y(x)$,

$$\int\frac{dt}{t^2+2t+200}=x+C.$$

$$\frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{199}})}{\sqrt{199}}=x+C.$$

So $$y(x)=\sqrt{199} \tan(\sqrt{199}(x+C))-1.$$

Comment: Would this also be a valid step: We start with $\int \frac{y'dx}{y^2+2y+200} =x+C$ and then substitute $ y'(x) dx = dy $ to get $\int \frac{dy}{y^2+2y+200} =x+C $ and then solve it like you have shown?

Comment: @Lone The steps are equivalent.